# bash shell script two variables in for loop

Tags: shell-script, for

```
for SLAVE_CLUSTER,MASTER_CLUSTER in $MASTER_CLUSTERS $SLAVE_CLUSTERS
do
      echo "Master cluster boxes are ${!MASTER_CLUSTER}"
      echo "Slave cluster boxes are ${!SLAVE_CLUSTER}"
done
```

I am trying to get value of `SLAVE_CLUSTER`,`MASTER_CLUSTER` in one for loop but i am getting errors. How can we get both variables in one `for` loop?

---

Here is my master and slave cluster variable

```
export MASTER_CLUSTER_1="MASTER1 MASTER2"
echo "MASTER_CLUSTER_1 = $MASTER_CLUSTER_1"
export MASTER_CLUSTER_2="MASTER1 MASTER2"
echo "MASTER_CLUSTER_2 = $MASTER_CLUSTER_2"
export SLAVE_CLUSTER_1="SLAVE1 SLAVE2 SLAVE3 SLAVE4"
echo "SLAVE_CLUSTER_1 = $SLAVE_CLUSTER_1"
export SLAVE_CLUSTER_2="SLAVE1 SLAVE2 SLAVE3 SLAVE4"
echo "SLAVE_CLUSTER_2 = $SLAVE_CLUSTER_2"
```

Comment: What does $MASTER_CLUSTER contain? What does $SLAVE_CLUSTER contain? (sample values are ok) If you are not listing box names as in @rcjohnson answer where there is a list of master boxes, and a separate list of slave cluster box names, then what is the desired way of listing that you want to see? And update the original question with this info if you can, thanks

Comment: Are you looking for every permutation of the contents of MASTER_CLUSTERS/SLAVE_CLUSTERS or a mapping from one to the other based on position?

Comment: use `while`. `for` does *one* thing, `while` does *anything* *`while`* true.

Comment: Here is my master and slave cluster variable

Comment: export MASTER_CLUSTER_1="MASTER1 MASTER2"
echo "MASTER_CLUSTER_1 = $MASTER_CLUSTER_1"

export MASTER_CLUSTER_2="MASTER1 MASTER2"
echo "MASTER_CLUSTER_2 = $MASTER_CLUSTER_2"

export SLAVE_CLUSTER_1="SLAVE1 SLAVE2 SLAVE3 SLAVE4"
echo "SLAVE_CLUSTER_1 = $SLAVE_CLUSTER_1"

export SLAVE_CLUSTER_2="SLAVE1 SLAVE2 SLAVE3 SLAVE4"
echo "SLAVE_CLUSTER_2 = $SLAVE_CLUSTER_2"

Comment: (a) Edit your question rather than posting details in the comments. (b) It looks like you have a serious design problem—you are hacking together multi-dimensional and/or associative arrays *in bash* with variable indirection rather than using a proper tool for the job.  I suspect you shouldn't be using `bash` for this at all, but should be calling `awk` from within bash to do what you need.

Comment: It's also totally unclear if MASTER1 SLAVE1 etc. are placeholders or variable names.  Right now in the values you posted, SLAVE_CLUSTER_1 and SLAVE_CLUSTER_2 are completely identical.  Please edit to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain I understand your need for a single loop. You could get the same output using two consecutive loops like this

```
for MASTER_CLUSTER in $MASTER_CLUSTERS

    do
          echo "Master cluster boxes are ${!MASTER_CLUSTER}"
    done

for SLAVE_CLUSTER in $SLAVE_CLUSTERS
    do
          echo "Slave cluster boxes are ${!SLAVE_CLUSTER}"
    done
```

or if the values must be alternated then

```
for MASTER_CLUSTER in $MASTER_CLUSTERS
    do 
    echo "Master cluster boxes are ${!MASTER_CLUSTER}"
    for SLAVE_CLUSTER in $SLAVE_CLUSTERS
       do
          echo "Slave cluster boxes are ${!SLAVE_CLUSTER}"
       done
    done
```

Comment: No THis will not be helpful. I have to grab Master and Slave cluster values in single loop only I have to do parallel operation for Master and slave boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Extending my answer based on the OP's clarification.  Again, you can use an array:

```
$ cat /tmp/foo.sh
#/bin/bash

# Sample values from OP
export MASTER_CLUSTER_1="MASTER1 MASTER2"
export MASTER_CLUSTER_2="MASTER3 MASTER4" # (edited to be unique)
export SLAVE_CLUSTER_1="SLAVE1 SLAVE2 SLAVE3 SLAVE4"
export SLAVE_CLUSTER_2="SLAVE5 SLAVE6 SLAVE7 SLAVE8" # (edited to be unique)

# Create two arrays, one for masters and one for slaves.  Each array has
# two elements -- strings containing space delimited hosts
declare -a master_array=( "${MASTER_CLUSTER_1}" "${MASTER_CLUSTER_2}" )
declare -a slave_array=( "${SLAVE_CLUSTER_1}" "${SLAVE_CLUSTER_2}" )

# For this to work, both arrays need to have the same number of elements
if [[ "${#master_array[@]}" == ${#slave_array[@]} ]]; then
    for ((i = 0; i < ${#master_array[@]}; ++i)); do
        echo "master: ${master_array[$i]}, slave: ${slave_array[$i]}"
    done
fi
```

Sample output:

```
$ bash /tmp/foo.sh
master: MASTER1 MASTER2, slave: SLAVE1 SLAVE2 SLAVE3 SLAVE4
master: MASTER3 MASTER4, slave: SLAVE5 SLAVE6 SLAVE7 SLAVE8
```

Comment: Here is my master and slave varibale

Comment: export MASTER_CLUSTER_1="MASTER1 MASTER2"
echo "MASTER_CLUSTER_1 = $MASTER_CLUSTER_1"

export MASTER_CLUSTER_2="MASTER1 MASTER2"
echo "MASTER_CLUSTER_2 = $MASTER_CLUSTER_2"

export SLAVE_CLUSTER_1="SLAVE1 SLAVE2 SLAVE3 SLAVE4"
echo "SLAVE_CLUSTER_1 = $SLAVE_CLUSTER_1"

export SLAVE_CLUSTER_2="SLAVE1 SLAVE2 SLAVE3 SLAVE4"
echo "SLAVE_CLUSTER_2 = $SLAVE_CLUSTER_2"

Comment: I want to grab value of Master_Cluster1 with Slave_Cluster_1 in one for loop.